# ModelBuilder seed data with relation keeped

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

it's probably very simple but i stuck and dont have idea how to solve it.
I have two entities:

```
    public class BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
    }
    public class Vat : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Rate { get; set; }
        public Country Country { get; set; }
    }
    public class Country : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Vat> Vats { get; set; }
    }
```

and definition:

```
        public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Vat> builder)
        {
            base.Configure(builder);
            builder.HasOne(e => e.Country).WithMany(e => e.Vats);
        }
```

Seed look like that:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().HasData(
            new Country { Id = 1, Code = "FR", Name = "France" },
            new Country { Id = 2, Code = "DE", Name = "Germany" },
            new Country { Id = 3, Code = "CZ", Name = "Czech" }
           );
        modelBuilder.Entity<Vat>().HasData(
           new Vat { Id = 1, Name = "23%", Rate = 23, IsActive = true, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now, Country = new Country { Id = 1 },  },
           new Vat { Id = 2, Name = "8%", Rate = 8, IsActive = true, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now, Country = new Country { Id = 1 } },
           new Vat { Id = 3, Name = "5%", Rate = 5, IsActive = true, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now, Country = new Country { Id = 1 } },
           new Vat { Id = 4, Name = "0%", Rate = 0, IsActive = true, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now, Country = new Country { Id = 1 } }
            );
```

But while i seeding Vat im getting this error:

```
The seed entity for entity type 'Vat' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'Country' set. To seed relationships,  add the entity seed to 'Vat' and specify the foreign key values {'CountryId'}.
```

Any idea what's the proper way to seed Vat entities and keep it related to Country?

Thank to [Bogdan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10054364/bogdan-girnyk) it works, but now i have similar problem with many to many relationship:

```
    public class Product : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal PriceMin { get; set; }
        public decimal PriceMax { get; set; }
        public decimal CostNetto { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Vat> Vats { get; set; }
    }
    public class Vat : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Rate { get; set; }
        public Country Country { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

tried something like that:

```
        var products = new List<object>()
        {
            new { Id=1, Name="Proszek Omo", Description="Proszek do prania Omo jest super", CostNetto=12m, PriceMin=14m, PriceMax=18m, ShortName="Omo", IsActive = true, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now, Vats=new List<object>{ new { VatsId = 1 } }, Tags=new List<object>{new {TagsId=1 }, new { TagsId = 3 } } }
        };
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasData(products);
```

but still getting this error:

```
The seed entity for entity type 'Product' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'Vats' set. To seed relationships,  add the entity seed to 'ProductVat (Dictionary<string, object>)' and specify the foreign key values {'ProductsId'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To seed entities with navigation properties you may use dynamic objects.
This way should work:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Vat>().HasData(
   new List<object>
        {
           new { Id = 1, Name = "23%", Rate = 23, IsActive = true, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now, CountryId = 1  },
           new { Id = 2, Name = "8%", Rate = 8, IsActive = true, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now, CountryId = 1  },
...
        }
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how we can seed many to many relationship in this case:

```
        var productVats = new List<object>()
        {
            new { ProductsId=1, VatsId=1},
            new { ProductsId=1, VatsId=5}
        };
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(p => p.Vats).WithMany(p => p.Products).UsingEntity(j => j.HasData(productVats));
```